# Infinite nesting Yup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I have an object that may contain children of the same type of object, potentially making it infinite nested. Here is a simplified version of the TS-interface.

```
interface Query {operation: Operation, innerQuery?: Query}
```

I'm using the Query interface in a form and want to use yup to validate it, but haven't found a way to make a yup object reference itself. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yup.lazy` for this.

```
const query = yup.object({
  innerQuery: yup.lazy(() => query.default(undefined)),
});
```

Calling `default(undefined)` is to prevent object from nesting itself indefinitely on casting it.